# Trying a Generic SP as a template for SELECT( for anti-injection purpose)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

was planed to be used :

for example :

```
tableName = TableCustomers 
column1 = UserName
column2 = UserMail
-- SP name ......and as zero will select all *, 'firstColName'....
SelectFromGivenTableWithOptionalGivenColumn, 0, 'UserName', '', 'AnyUserName', ''
```

or better copied from `SSMS` generated  execution Script

```
USE [KwPos]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SelectFromGivenTableWithOptionalGivenColumns]
    @tableName = 'TableCustomers',
    @zeroForAllTable = 0,
    @Column = 'UserName',
    @Column2 = '',
    @ColVal = 'AnyUserName',
    @ColVal2 = ''
```

**ERROR**

```
Invalid column name 'AnyUserName'.
```

this is the SQL of SP (tried both names of column using `SysName` & `nvarchar` resulting in the same error)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectFromGivenTableWithOptionalGivenColumns] 
    @tableName sysname ='', 
    @zeroForAllTable bit = 0,
    @Column sysname = '',
    @Column2 sysname = '',  
    @ColVal varchar(111) = '',
    @ColVal2 varchar(111) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @q varchar(1000)
    if(@zeroForAllTable !=0)
        begin
            if(@Column !='' AND @Column2 !='')
                begin
                    if(@Column != '' AND @ColVal !='' AND @Column2 != '' AND @ColVal2 !='')
                        begin   
                            set @q= 'SELECT ' + @Column + ' FROM ' + @tableName + ' where ' + @Column + ' = ' + @ColVal + ' AND ' + @Column2 + ' = ' + @ColVal2;
                        end
                    else if(@Column !='' AND @ColVal ='')
                        begin
                            set @q = 'SELECT '+ @Column +' FROM ' + @tableName;
                        end
                end
            else
            if(@Column !='' AND @Column = '')
                begin
                    if(@Column != '' AND @ColVal !='')
                        begin   
                            set @q= 'SELECT ' + @Column + ' FROM ' + @tableName + ' where ' + @Column + ' = ' + @ColVal;
                        end
                    else if(@Column !='' AND @ColVal ='')
                        begin
                            set @q = 'SELECT '+ @Column + ' FROM ' + @tableName;
                        end
                end
        end
    else
        begin
            if(@Column !='' AND @Column2 !='')
                begin
                    if(@Column != '' AND @ColVal !='')
                        begin   
                            set @q= 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName + ' where ' + @Column+ ' = ' + @ColVal + ' AND ' + @Column2 + ' = ' + @ColVal2;
                        end
                    else if(@Column !='' AND @ColVal ='')
                        begin
                            set @q = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName;
                        end
                end
            else
            if(@Column !='' AND @Column2 = '')
                begin
                    if(@Column != '' AND @ColVal !='')
                        begin   
                            set @q= 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName + ' where ' + @Column + ' = ' + @ColVal;
                        end
                    else if(@Column !='' AND @ColVal ='')
                        begin
                            set @q = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName;
                        end
                    else 
                        begin
                            set @q = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName;
                        end
                end
        end

    exec (@q)

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just did the opposite of stopping SQL injection. By creating the query dynamically without encoding values properly, you potentially open up a giant hole for SQL injection.

The query that you tried to create would be:

```
SELECT * FROM TableCustomers where UserName = 'AnyUserName'
```

but you created:

```
SELECT * FROM TableCustomers where UserName = AnyUserName
```

You can add the missing apostrophes, but the injection hole is still open. Imagine that the user name was input from a user, and instead of entering `AnyUserName` he entered `';drop table TableCustomers;--`, then the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM TableCustomers where UserName = '';drop table TableCustomers;--'
```

Oops, your table is gone.

(Compulsory XKCD reference: http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: thanks for your answer!, i will learn some more, checking up your link. thanks again for your time reviewing this mass of code

Comment: added another option for your inspection if you're still here..

Answer (score 0):

taken from this [Link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)
(3rd Example)

is this code safe enough ?

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)
SET @columnList = 'CustomerID, ContactName, City'
SET @city = 'London'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM customers WHERE City = @city'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@city nvarchar(75)', @city = @city
```

i mean... could you **easily** still potentially kill some data here ?

Comment: That is safe, as long as the `@columnList` value can't be altered by the user. For future reference, you should have added that to your question by editing it, not as an answer to the question.